# [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: javascript, mysql, server, sequelize-cli

Hi I am new with Sequelize ORM. I am following some tutorial and while hands-on, I am facing the problem in connecting the MySQL database with server.

```
ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at ConnectionManager.connect (G:\projects\chatApp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:116:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    fatal: true
  },
  original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    fatal: true
  }
}
```

Serve.js

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server')

const { sequelize } = require('./models')

const resolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers')
const typeDefs = require('./graphql/typeDefs')

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
})

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`)

    sequelize
        .authenticate()
        .then(() => console.log('Database connected!!'))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
})
```

config.json

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "database": "database_dev",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I am not able to connect to the database?

Comment: ECONNREFUSED means the server your are trying to connect dosnt accept connections. Does your mysql server run ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is showing "Could not connect, the server may not be running."

Comment: There is your problem! You mysql server are not working

Comment: How could I fix that? As it is unable to connect to localhost.

Comment: Have you a mysql server installed you on your machine ?
I would start the mysql server and look in the log files why it dosnt start properly

Comment: Got it! Fixed it. Actually, I was using MySQL Workbench and in the documents, it was written MySQL server not required.

Answer (score 0):

1. run MySql installer
2. reconfigure the MySql Server. it will work fine.

[check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkJuG.jpg)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

Check port of mysql you are using, maybe 3307 ?